# Converting 26.62 NOx µg/L into mM (millimolars)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, stoichiometry, mole

I have to convert  a whole lot of nutrient data : $\ce{NH_4}$, $\ce{PO_4}$ and $\ce{NO_x}$ data that is in µg/L into mM (millimolars).

Could someone give me an example for 26.62 $\ce{NO_x}$ µg/L? or 7.73 $\ce{PO_4}$ µg/L? or 14.39 $\ce{NH_4}$ µg/L?

I have a large data set in Excel to convert and send to someone and want to get it right. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would make it easy for yourself and convert your µg/L to g/L. You can then divide it by the formula weight to obtain the molarity (in M). After this it is just a simple conversion to mM.

I suppose in Excel you can create a new column and use a formula something like this:

=((CELL/10<sup>6</sup>)/Formula weight)*1000

So for your example of phosphate:

=((0.00000773)/94.97)*1000

=0.00008139 mM // 8.139x10<sup>-5</sup> mM

Comment: The hard part is what formula weight to use for the NOx.  I suspect that the "&mu;g" of NOx really means of &mu;g of _nitrogen_ as NOx.  If I'm right, then the NOx formula weight is 14, but this would be an important detail to confirm about the OPs data set.

Comment: Thanks Curt, I did what you said and sent the spreadsheet away to have rechecked and all was spot on. The molar mass NOx was 14, PO4 was 31 and NH4 was 14 so I guess they're not taking the 'O' mass into account? Thanks so much for your help. Paul.